# Alternative to POSIX message queues

Tags: linux, ipc, message-queue, mq

I am using POSIX message queues in a non-root system. I am running into significant issues with unlinking and cleaning. I can't see opened message queues and then write a routine to clean them.

I was wondering if one of the two are possible:

- Create POSIX mqueue locally, in $PWD or something
- Get an alternative message queue library instead of the standard one from Linux.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can try is to see whether you can go by using a unix domain datagram sockets instead of posix message queues, in particular SOC_SEQPACKET variety of those:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html

If this is not enough, there are plenty of message queue abstraction libraries out there, such as a popular ZeroMQ: http://zeromq.org/